# Calculate the average and standard deviation, rubiks cube style

Tags: code-golf, statistics

### Introduction

When solving a rubiks cube, one often write down the times like this

```
11.91, (11.28), (12.32)
```

This is called a average of 3, while a average of 5 looks like this

```
13.36, (11.89), 12.31, (16.44), 12.26
```

Note how the *worst* and *best* times have parenthesis around them. When calculating the average of `5` these times are removed. For an average of 3 the worst and best times are NOT removed. Similarly when calculating the standard deviation.

When taking the average of more than 12 cubes things start to get a bit harder. The general rule of thumb is:

**When solving fewer than 5 cubes, do not remove any times when calculating avg or std**

**When evaluating fewer than 12 times, remove the best and worst time when calculating avg or std**

**When evaluating fewer than 40 times remove the 1/12 worst and 1/12 best times rounded down the nearest integer.**

**When evaluating more than 40 times remove the 1/20 worst times and the 1/20 best times rounded down to the nearest integer.**

For an average of `100` this would mean we would remove the `(100/20) = 5` best solves and `(100/20) = 5` worst solves. Giving

```
14.88, 12.28, 13.76, 16.06, 13.82, 13.26, 14.57, 12.56, 15.02, 14.73, 
13.87, 14.59, 15.17, (18.48), 12.09, 12.76, 11.65, 14.14, 12.83, 14.30, 
13.28, 14.02, 12.55, 15.18, 13.65, 12.72, 14.86, 14.08, 15.07, 12.88, 13.78,
13.88, 14.63, 12.72, (10.10), 14.70, 12.82, 13.27, 13.82, 14.74, (11.22), 
13.46, 12.66, 14.06, (10.58), 15.06, (18.27), 13.39, (17.88), (18.67), 
15.38, 15.60, 14.24, 12.64, 15.51, 14.23, 16.71, 14.55, 14.32, 12.33, 11.90, 
13.65, 13.69, 13.90, 13.15, (9.61), 12.91, 13.39, 11.77, 12.64, 15.22, 
14.69, 12.76, 15.10, 11.91, (11.28), 12.32, 14.28, 14.46, 14.66, 14.15, 
15.27, (17.73), 12.70, 14.58, 11.84, 13.25, 13.36, 13.26, 15.72, 14.15, 
12.77, 15.26, 12.87, 12.96, 13.57, 14.50, 14.30, 14.57, 12.69
```

### The challenge

The problem at hand is to take a (large) list of numbers and figure out the best average or std of a subset of these.

**input**

```
list, n, avg or std
```

Write a program that takes in a list of numbers formated exactly as comma seperated numbers `12.91, 13.39, ...` or `[12.91, 13,39 ... ]` You can assume that the list only contains real valued positive numbers less than `2^32`.

A number `n` indicating how many numbers to average or take the std of, if `n=0` one should take the average / std of all the numbers.

A string `avg` or `std` indicating if one should return the lowest average of `n` numbers or the [lowest standard deviation (std)](https://revisionmaths.com/gcse-maths-revision/statistics-handling-data/standard-deviation). A negative `n` or a non integer should throw an error, blank or return false.

**Output**

The output should be exactly on the form

```
avg = ...
list of of numbers
```

or

```
std = ...
list of of numbers
```

As shown in the examples. Note that the best and worst times are marked with brackets as given by the rules above. **The function should return the `n` consecutive times with the *lowest* `avg` or `std`** At every 12 time, a newline should be inserted.

### Test case

I will use the following list of `200` numbers to base my tests on

```
15.86, 17.02, 24.01, 21.01, 15.93, 14.86, 18.43, 12.52, 18.48, 19.85, 13.01, 14.92, 13.07, 13.44, 13.07, 15.08, 12.70, 13.59, 15.22, 11.88, 13.26, 13.62, 12.85, 16.88, 15.78, 15.94, 14.88, 12.28, 13.76, 16.06, 13.82, 13.26, 14.57, 12.56, 15.02, 14.73, 13.87, 14.59, 15.17, 18.48, 12.09, 12.76, 11.65, 14.14, 12.83, 14.30, 13.28, 14.02, 12.55, 15.18, 13.65, 12.72, 14.86, 14.08, 15.07, 12.88, 13.78, 13.88, 14.63, 12.72, 10.10, 14.70, 12.82, 13.27, 13.82, 14.74, 11.22, 13.46, 12.66, 14.06, 10.58, 15.06, 18.27, 13.39, 17.88, 18.67, 15.38, 15.60, 14.24, 12.64, 15.51, 14.23, 16.71, 14.55, 14.32, 12.33, 11.90, 13.65, 13.69, 13.90, 13.15, 9.61, 12.91, 13.39, 11.77, 12.64, 15.22, 14.69, 12.76, 15.10, 11.91, 11.28, 12.32, 14.28, 14.46, 14.66, 14.15, 15.27, 17.73, 12.70, 14.58, 11.84, 13.25, 13.36, 13.26, 15.72, 14.15, 12.77, 15.26, 12.87, 12.96, 13.57, 14.50, 14.30, 14.57, 12.69, 15.21, 14.45, 14.90, 14.91, 15.66, 15.87, 14.79, 15.69, 17.37, 15.42, 12.11, 14.89, 13.39, 12.62, 13.42, 14.07, 14.85, 13.23, 14.05, 14.43, 13.36, 14.19, 14.16, 14.66, 12.02, 12.56, 12.69, 12.55, 14.36, 15.79, 12.53, 12.51, 12.15, 15.60, 13.42, 12.87, 13.02, 15.66, 13.18, 14.77, 13.57, 13.86, 12.26, 14.48, 14.68, 11.85, 14.82, 13.74, 13.85, 15.05, 14.78, 14.43, 12.72, 14.39, 15.06, 15.28, 12.06, 14.59, 15.49, 11.66, 14.83, 14.09, 11.62, 15.96, 14.77, 14.99, 14.20, 12.35, 17.62, 11.66, 13.46, 15.24, 14.85, 13.48
```

**Input 0:**

```
list, 3, avg
```

**Output 0:**

```
avg = 11.84
11.91, (11.28), (12.32)
```

**Input 1:**

```
list, 12, avg
```

**Output 1:**

```
avg = 12.88
(9.61), 12.91, 13.39, 11.77, 12.64, (15.22), 14.69, 12.76, 15.10, 11.91, 11.28, 12.32
```

**Input 2:**

```
list, 12, std
```

**Output 2:**

```
std = 0.44
15.21, 14.45, 14.90, 14.91, 15.66, 15.87, 14.79, 15.69, (17.37), 15.42, (12.11), 14.89
```

**Input 3:**

```
list, 0, std
```

**Output 3:**

```
std = 1.21
15.86, 17.02, (24.01), (21.01), 15.93, 14.86, (18.43), 12.52, (18.48), (19.85), 13.01, 14.92, 
13.07, 13.44, 13.07, 15.08, 12.70, 13.59, 15.22, 11.88, 13.26, 13.62, 12.85, 16.88, 
15.78, 15.94, 14.88, 12.28, 13.76, 16.06, 13.82, 13.26, 14.57, 12.56, 15.02, 14.73, 
13.87, 14.59, 15.17, (18.48), 12.09, 12.76, (11.65), 14.14, 12.83, 14.30, 13.28, 14.02, 
12.55, 15.18, 13.65, 12.72, 14.86, 14.08, 15.07, 12.88, 13.78, 13.88, 14.63, 12.72, 
(10.10), 14.70, 12.82, 13.27, 13.82, 14.74, (11.22), 13.46, 12.66, 14.06, (10.58), 15.06, 
(18.27), 13.39, (17.88), (18.67), 15.38, 15.60, 14.24, 12.64, 15.51, 14.23, 16.71, 14.55, 
14.32, 12.33, 11.90, 13.65, 13.69, 13.90, 13.15, (9.61), 12.91, 13.39, (11.77), 12.64, 
15.22, 14.69, 12.76, 15.10, 11.91, (11.28), 12.32, 14.28, 14.46, 14.66, 14.15, 15.27, 
(17.73), 12.70, 14.58, 11.84, 13.25, 13.36, 13.26, 15.72, 14.15, 12.77, 15.26, 12.87, 
12.96, 13.57, 14.50, 14.30, 14.57, 12.69, 15.21, 14.45, 14.90, 14.91, 15.66, 15.87, 
14.79, 15.69, 17.37, 15.42, 12.11, 14.89, 13.39, 12.62, 13.42, 14.07, 14.85, 13.23, 
14.05, 14.43, 13.36, 14.19, 14.16, 14.66, 12.02, 12.56, 12.69, 12.55, 14.36, 15.79, 
12.53, 12.51, 12.15, 15.60, 13.42, 12.87, 13.02, 15.66, 13.18, 14.77, 13.57, 13.86, 
12.26, 14.48, 14.68, 11.85, 14.82, 13.74, 13.85, 15.05, 14.78, 14.43, 12.72, 14.39, 
15.06, 15.28, 12.06, 14.59, 15.49, (11.66), 14.83, 14.09, (11.62), 15.96, 14.77, 14.99, 
14.20, 12.35, 17.62, (11.66), 13.46, 15.24, 14.85, 13.48
```

Split the lines at every 12 number.

**Input 4:**

```
list, 201, avg
```

**Output 5:**

```
Throw `Error` or `False`.
```

**Input 6:**

```
list, 1, avg
```

**Output 6:**

```
avg = 9.61
(9.61)
```

**Input 8:**

```
list, 1, std
```

**Output 8:**

```
std = 0
(15.86)
```

just return the first element of the list.

## Scoring

Submissions will be scored in **bytes**. I recommend [this website](http://bytesizematters.com) to keep track of your byte count, though you can use any counter you like. Like always whitespace counts as bytes.

Remove 25% of your byte count if your function has the ability to switch between highest avg and std, and lowest avg and std. Eg input on the form

```
list, n, avg / std, high / low
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the lowest score wins!

Comment: Can a function be written?

Comment: yeah =) No problem

Comment: This is an old post, but I have some questions. Why is output 0 not 10.10? (The 3 lowest values in your example list are [9.61, 10.10, 10.58].) Why are multiple values in parentheses in output 3? (The description just says that those are the "smallest" and "largest", but that's not the case.) Finally, why is output 8 zero? The standard deviation of only 1 number is undefined (because it involves division by zero). I think I have a neat solution to this puzzle, but I'm not sure because the details are so vague...

Answer (score 2):

## Java 10, <s>944</s> <s>903</s> 861 bytes

```java
import java.util.*;interface M{static void main(String[]a){var f=a[2];int n=new Short(a[1]),i=0,l,j,k;if(n<0)return;List<Double>L=new Stack(),t,r,R=L,u,U=L,S=L,V=L;for(var s:a[0].split(","))L.add(new Double(s));l=L.size();n=n<1?l:n;i=0;double m=99,M=m,q,Q,x,y,z;do{for(t=new Stack(),x=y=j=0;j<n;)t.add(L.get(i+j++));for(k=n<12?0:n<40?n/12:n/20,j=k=k<1?1:k,u=new ArrayList(t),r=new Stack();j-->0;){r.add(q=Collections.min(t));r.add(Q=Collections.max(t));if(n>4){t.remove(q);t.remove(Q);}}for(var T:t)x+=T;x/=k=n>4?n-2*k:n;if(x<m){m=x;R=r;U=u;}for(var T:t)y+=(z=T-x)*z;y=Math.sqrt(y/k);if(y<M){M=y;S=r;V=u;}}while(i++<l-n);j=f.charAt(0)-97;System.out.println(f+" = "+f.format(f="%.2f",q=j<1?n<2?Collections.min(L):m:n<2?0:M));i=0;for(var o:j<1?U:n<2?L.subList(0,1):V)System.out.print(f.format((j<1?R:S).remove(o)?"(%.2f)":f,n+j<2?q:o)+(++i<n&i%12>0?", ":"\n"));}}
```

Full program requirement, strict I/O formatting, validating.. sigh.. >.>

Verify all test cases: [3,avg](https://tio.run/##XVRdU@M6DP0rmc7snZi4xnYc56ums3PvY/sABV64PGQhhfQjpanLtnT47V3HchvYBxCRJZ2jI4lZ8V70Z8/z47Favq0a7c2Mg2x1tSAXeVXrspkWT6U3Pmx0oasn731VPXvLoqr9iW6q@uXhsUCH96Lxpqp44I9tileruvztTV5NOb94YI8IV4riBZ7heV5N/XpAUVPqbVPno2qjB/@ttr8W5dUIsnTxNPcR1rjBN2qEt/jO/J6Yn3s1yqerxm/BNlnxQB/J5m1Rab@HewiNSPH87LcVoJy/QShfqBHZVB@lj3LDacCGi6zODZf82cZ4S5WmeKyWeI2v8Q7v8Yd5ObQg@huZndqrmUmbDeocaYs0Ii@l9qtgFgQGqE2Ztwh8SLN6IOiwvmQ8qy85xTM1V3ODzbI53tqyP5um2Let@xrh5itSPuv3r2iODo0FWat/V4tF@aSrVb0hSyO6NmDwdv39rdjZt1beK4EOmjTlcvVe@muUn/@@Rvnn50nC20yjXaBu892lIWiShnWfX8xbgab@brBEh6Xa5Teqye/UNv@Wtg@U/6Fu@zt08ZHv1bjQr2SzNsPeX84thf1gjA5jtc8nJv2@Tf/8/VqZoVRBMFj0a9OnmpKn16L5qX2K@mmcT/YbXS7JaqvJm9krvaj9adDzlNcLpsSALwvtT1XvB@HTHl6rmRG0HvDh3/qMULbM2geajVs5zNBOzFdZm3RnX81abH/ZCVDMUHaP/ob3z6B@m3WTTdBJxRUa9vyWB@plU1wHM1Nvna1Q4AdBNaj/qX4wfkWHPez1st7/tdlN0/7xeGQRSST2WEwoxx4XhDJjmDXmLQ2NERCSENF@cRJx@EqMSUkSGRNCgiAph6/YGiG6r4jQxKbH1Dqj1Dp5m8BIklgnl9ZIbiNtaQlvEYnBpAIoQTEOebG0kRTSE94VEySKgbUEEtw64xAiYwgBLizuGuOEpkBXWoIyspFMADPQJYRWLAkBpQ1QBMWAmc0zVXgnpAAlItCFn3qPwSRQTIZdHiWMAmsKCa6/uOvWvAnLk8ObkDZSOjxpq0QOFqbp0sPUjt/CJkTCqEKIlADLoWkprDOCSfPQSh7DVwTyhCBBGFouKe0kMCa1xjmZcaZEMhufso4KI3H8FY5De/LLNCLQg0EeA/05gIvTNAS07hRgMBTbcwzTd5soQBazgrCsHNiGstuh6DQ@5oYJInHQOAG6KSREbqNotyDnFZRu5UEyAZKlEJLCwUnAc3sZQ4KEEYUAK0BjBlWStJOOw@GEECJgv8TpQjnsLAVYEXZtmsZSMF804@d9lh15fh6008U53T8GmKbTWtKOi1MphJquzRBuRICeTroQboSfrle4c3AzAnR3ADFMLAE811icdP2d7y5Mu82PTvtC5dfjF7B8bl/cgVPnBNap7OiaiYFmHG4yjOyMJO@quCuM4H7OcxDJMTwW7y9/AA) ; [12,avg](https://tio.run/##XVRdU@M6DP0rmc7snZi4xnYc56ums3PvY/sABV64PGQhhfQjpanLtnT47V3HchvYBxCRJZ2jI4lZ8V70Z8/z47Favq0a7c2Mg2x1tSAXeVXrspkWT6U3Pmx0oasn731VPXvLoqr9iW6q@uXhsUCH96Lxpqp44I9tileruvztTV5NOb94YI8IV4riBZ7heV5N/XpAUVPqbVPno2qjB/@ttr8W5dUIsnTxNPcR1rjBN2qEt/jO/J6Yn3s1yqerxm/BNlnxQB/J5m1Rab@HewiNSPH87LcVoJy/QShfqBHZVB@lj3LDacCGi6zODZf82cZ4S5WmeKyWeI2v8Q7v8Yd5ObQg@huZndqrmUmbDeocaYs0Ii@l9qtgFgQGqE2Ztwh8SLN6IOiwvmQ8qy85xTM1V3ODzbI53tqyP5um2Let@xrh5itSPuv3r2iODo0FWat/V4tF@aSrVb0hSyO6NmDwdv39rdjZt1beK4EOmjTlcvVe@muUn/@@Rvnn50nC20yjXaBu892lIWiShnWfX8xbgab@brBEh6Xa5Teqye/UNv@Wtg@U/6Fu@zt08ZHv1bjQr2SzNsPeX84thf1gjA5jtc8nJv2@Tf/8/VqZoVRBMFj0a9OnmpKn16L5qX2K@mmcT/YbXS7JaqvJm9krvaj9adDzlNcLpsSALwvtT1XvB@HTHl6rmRG0HvDh3/qMULbM2geajVs5zNBOzFdZm3RnX81abH/ZCVDMUHaP/ob3z6B@m3WTTdBJxRUa9vyWB@plU1wHM1Nvna1Q4AdBNaj/qX4wfkWHPez1st7/tdlN0/7xeGQRSST2WEwoxx4XhDJjmDXmLQ2NERCSENF@cRJx@EqMSUkSGRNCgiAph6/YGiG6r4jQxKbH1Dqj1Dp5m8BIklgnl9ZIbiNtaQlvEYnBpAIoQTEOebG0kRTSE94VEySKgbUEEtw64xAiYwgBLizuGuOEpkBXWoIyspFMADPQJYRWLAkBpQ1QBMWAmc0zVXgnpAAlItCFn3qPwSRQTIZdHiWMAmsKCa6/uOvWvAnLk8ObkDZSOjxpq0QOFqbp0sPUjt/CJkTCqEKIlADLoWkprDOCSfPQSh7DVwTyhCBBGFouKe0kMCa1xjmZcaZEMhufso4KI3H8FY5De/LLNCLQg0EeA/05gIvTNAS07hRgMBTbcwzTd5soQBazgrCsHNiGstuh6DQ@5oYJInHQOAG6KSREbqNotyDnFZRu5UEyAZKlEJLCwUnAc3sZQ4KEEYUAK0BjBlWStJOOw@GEECJgv8TpQjnsLAVYEXZtmsZSMF804@d9lh15fh6008U53T8GmKbTWtKOi1MphJquzRBuRICeTroQboSfrle4c3AzAnR3ADFMLAE811icdP2d7y5Mu82PTvtC5dfjF7B8bl/cgVPnBNap7OiaiYFmHG4yjOyMJO@quCuM4H7OcxDJkfFj8f7yBw) ; [12,std](https://tio.run/##XVRdU@M6DP0rmczsnXjjGttxnK@azs69j@0DFHjh8pCl7ZJ@pDR12ZYOv73rWG4D@wAisqRzdCQxL9/K3nyyOJ2q1eu60d7cOMhOV0vyvahqPW1m5fPUGx23utTVs/e2ribeqqzqYKybqv71@FSi41vZeDNVPvKnNsWrVT397Y1fTLmgfGRPCFeK4iWe40VRzYK6T1Ez1bumLobVVvf/W@9@LqfXQ8jS5fMiQFjjBt@qId7he/N7bH4e1LCYrZugBdvm5SN9ItvXZaUDH/sIDUk5mQRtBSgXbBEqlmpIttX7NECF4dRng2VeF4ZLMbEx3kplGR6pFd7gG7zHB/xuXo4tiP5CZq8Oam7S5v26QNoiDcmvqQ6qcB6GBqhNWbQIfEDzui/ooL5iPK@vOMVztVALg83yBd7Zsj@apjy0rQca4eYzUjHv9a5pgY6NBdmof9fL5fRZV@t6S1ZGdG3A4O3m61u5t2@tvNcCHTVppqv12zTYoOLy9w0qPj7OEt7lGu1DdVfsrwxBkzSoe/z7ohVoFuz7K3RcqX1xq5riXu2KL2mHUAXv6q63R9/fi4MalfqFbDdm2IerhaVw6I/QcaQOxdikP7TpH79fKjOUKgz7y15t@lQz8vxSNj90QFEvS4rxYaunK7LeafJq9kov62AW@p7y/HBGDPiq1MFM@d8In/l4o@ZG0LrPB3/rM0T5Km8faD5q5TBDOzNf523SvX01a7H7aSdAMUP5A/obPriABm3WbT5GZxXXaOAHLQ/k5zNch3NTb5OvURiEYdWv/6m@MX5NBz72/Nz/vza7ado/nU4sJqnEHksI5djjglBmDLPGvGWRMQJCUiLaL05iDl@pMRlJY2MiSBAk4/CVWCNE9xUTmtr0hFpnnFknbxMYSVPr5NIayW2kLS3hLSYJmEwAJSjGIS@RNpJCesq7YoLECbCWQIJbZxJBZAIhwIUlXWOc0AzoSktQxjaSCWAGukTQiiUhoLQBiqEYMLN5pgrvhBSgRAy68HPvCZgUismoy6OEUWBNIcH1l3TdmjdheXJ4E9JGSocnbZXYwcI0XXqU2fFb2JRIGFUEkRJgOTQthXXGMGkeWckT@IpBnggkiCLLJaOdBMZk1jgnM86MSGbjM9ZRYSRJPsNxaE9@mkYMejDIY6A/B3BxnoaA1p0CDIZie05g@m4TBchiVhCWlQPbSHY7FJ/Hx9wwQSQOGqdAN4OE2G0U7RbksoLSrTxIJkCyDEIyODgJeG4vE0iQMKIIYAVozKBKmnXScTicCEIE7Jc4XyiHnaUAK6KuTdNYBuaTZvyyz7Ijzy@Ddro4p/vHANN0WkvacXEqRVDTtRnBjQjQ00kXwY3w8/UKdw5uRoDuDiCBiaWA5xpL0q6/y91FWbf58XlfqPx8/AKWz@2LO3DqnMA6kx1dMzHQjMNNRrGdkeRdFXeFMdzPZQ4iPTF@2urJHw) ; [0,std](https://tio.run/##XVRdU@M6DP0rmczsnXjjGttxnK@azs69j@0DFHjh8pCl7ZJ@pDR12ZYOv73rWG4D@wAisqRzdCQxL9/K3nyyOJ2q1eu60d7cOMhOV0vyvahqPW1m5fPUGx23utTVs/e2ribeqqzqYKybqv71@FSi41vZeDNVPvKnNsWrVT397Y1fTLmgfGRPCFeK4iWe40VRzYK6T1Ez1bumLobVVvf/W@9@LqfXQ8jS5fMiQFjjBt@qId7he/N7bH4e1LCYrZugBdvm5SN9ItvXZaUDH/sIDUk5mQRtBSgXbBEqlmpIttX7NECF4dRng2VeF4ZLMbEx3kplGR6pFd7gG7zHB/xuXo4tiP5CZq8Oam7S5v26QNoiDcmvqQ6qcB6GBqhNWbQIfEDzui/ooL5iPK@vOMVztVALg83yBd7Zsj@apjy0rQca4eYzUjHv9a5pgY6NBdmof9fL5fRZV@t6S1ZGdG3A4O3m61u5t2@tvNcCHTVppqv12zTYoOLy9w0qPj7OEt7lGu1DdVfsrwxBkzSoe/z7ohVoFuz7K3RcqX1xq5riXu2KL2mHUAXv6q63R9/fi4MalfqFbDdm2IerhaVw6I/QcaQOxdikP7TpH79fKjOUKgz7y15t@lQz8vxSNj90QFEvS4rxYaunK7LeafJq9kov62AW@p7y/HBGDPiq1MFM@d8In/l4o@ZG0LrPB3/rM0T5Km8faD5q5TBDOzNf523SvX01a7H7aSdAMUP5A/obPriABm3WbT5GZxXXaOAHLQ/k5zNch3NTb5OvURiEYdWv/6m@MX5NBz72/Nz/vza7ado/nU4sJqnEHksI5djjglBmDLPGvGWRMQJCUiLaL05iDl@pMRlJY2MiSBAk4/CVWCNE9xUTmtr0hFpnnFknbxMYSVPr5NIayW2kLS3hLSYJmEwAJSjGIS@RNpJCesq7YoLECbCWQIJbZxJBZAIhwIUlXWOc0AzoSktQxjaSCWAGukTQiiUhoLQBiqEYMLN5pgrvhBSgRAy68HPvCZgUismoy6OEUWBNIcH1l3TdmjdheXJ4E9JGSocnbZXYwcI0XXqU2fFb2JRIGFUEkRJgOTQthXXGMGkeWckT@IpBnggkiCLLJaOdBMZk1jgnM86MSGbjM9ZRYSRJPsNxaE9@mkYMejDIY6A/B3BxnoaA1p0CDIZie05g@m4TBchiVhCWlQPbSHY7FJ/Hx9wwQSQOGqdAN4OE2G0U7RbksoLSrTxIJkCyDEIyODgJeG4vE0iQMKIIYAVozKBKmnXScTicCEIE7Jc4XyiHnaUAK6KuTdNYBuaTZvyyz7Ijzy@Ddro4p/vHANN0WkvacXEqRVDTtRnBjQjQ00kXwY3w8/UKdw5uRoDuDiCBiaWA5xpL0q6/y91FWbf58XlfqPx8/AKWz@2LO3DqnMA6kx1dMzHQjMNNRrGdkeRdFXeFMdzPZQ4iPdHTVk/@AA) ; [201,avg](https://tio.run/##XVRdU@M6DP0rmc7snZi4xnYc56ums3PvY/sABV64PGQhhfQjpanLtnT47V3HchvYBxCRJZ2jI4lZ8V70Z8/z47Favq0a7c2Mg2x1tSAXeVXrspkWT6U3Pmx0oasn731VPXvLoqr9iW6q@uXhsUCH96Lxpqp44I9tileruvztTV5NOb94YI8IV4riBZ7heV5N/XpAUVPqbVPno2qjB/@ttr8W5dUIsnTxNPcR1rjBN2qEt/jO/J6Yn3s1yqerxm/BNlnxQB/J5m1Rab@HewiNSPH87LcVoJy/QShfqBHZVB@lj3LDacCGi6zODZf82cZ4S5WmeKyWeI2v8Q7v8Yd5ObQg@huZndqrmUmbDeocaYs0Ii@l9qtgFgQGqE2Ztwh8SLN6IOiwvmQ8qy85xTM1V3ODzbI53tqyP5um2Let@xrh5itSPuv3r2iODo0FWat/V4tF@aSrVb0hSyO6NmDwdv39rdjZt1beK4EOmjTlcvVe@muUn/@@Rvnn50nC20yjXaBu892lIWiShnWfX8xbgab@brBEh6Xa5Teqye/UNv@Wtg@U/6Fu@zt08ZHv1bjQr2SzNsPeX84thf1gjA5jtc8nJv2@Tf/8/VqZoVRBMFj0a9OnmpKn16L5qX2K@mmcT/YbXS7JaqvJm9krvaj9adDzlNcLpsSALwvtT1XvB@HTHl6rmRG0HvDh3/qMULbM2geajVs5zNBOzFdZm3RnX81abH/ZCVDMUHaP/ob3z6B@m3WTTdBJxRUa9vyWB@plU1wHM1Nvna1Q4AdBNaj/qX4wfkWHPez1st7/tdlN0/7xeGQRSST2WEwoxx4XhDJjmDXmLQ2NERCSENF@cRJx@EqMSUkSGRNCgiAph6/YGiG6r4jQxKbH1Dqj1Dp5m8BIklgnl9ZIbiNtaQlvEYnBpAIoQTEOebG0kRTSE94VEySKgbUEEtw64xAiYwgBLizuGuOEpkBXWoIyspFMADPQJYRWLAkBpQ1QBMWAmc0zVXgnpAAlItCFn3qPwSRQTIZdHiWMAmsKCa6/uOvWvAnLk8ObkDZSOjxpq0QOFqbp0sPUjt/CJkTCqEKIlADLoWkprDOCSfPQSh7DVwTyhCBBGFouKe0kMCa1xjmZcaZEMhufso4KI3H8FY5De/LLNCLQg0EeA/05gIvTNAS07hRgMBTbcwzTd5soQBazgrCsHNiGstuh6DQ@5oYJInHQOAG6KSREbqNotyDnFZRu5UEyAZKlEJLCwUnAc3sZQ4KEEYUAK0BjBlWStJOOw@GEECJgv8TpQjnsLAVYEXZtmsZSMF804@d9lh15fh6008U53T8GmKbTWtKOi1MphJquzRBuRICeTroQboSfrle4c3AzAnR3ADFMLAE811icdP2d7y5Mu82PTvtC5dfjF7B8bl/cgVPnBNap7OiaiYFmHG4yjOyMJO@quCuM4H7OcxDJkVN2LN5f/gA) ; [1,avg](https://tio.run/##XVRdU@M6DP0rmc7snZi4xnYc56ums3PvY/sABV64PGQhhfQjpanLtnT47V3HchvYBxCRJZ2jI4lZ8V70Z8/z47Favq0a7c2Mg2x1tSAXeVXrspkWT6U3Pmx0oasn731VPXvLoqr9iW6q@uXhsUCH96Lxpqp44I9tileruvztTV5NOb94YI8IV4riBZ7heV5N/XpAUVPqbVPno2qjB/@ttr8W5dUIsnTxNPcR1rjBN2qEt/jO/J6Yn3s1yqerxm/BNlnxQB/J5m1Rab@HewiNSPH87LcVoJy/QShfqBHZVB@lj3LDacCGi6zODZf82cZ4S5WmeKyWeI2v8Q7v8Yd5ObQg@huZndqrmUmbDeocaYs0Ii@l9qtgFgQGqE2Ztwh8SLN6IOiwvmQ8qy85xTM1V3ODzbI53tqyP5um2Let@xrh5itSPuv3r2iODo0FWat/V4tF@aSrVb0hSyO6NmDwdv39rdjZt1beK4EOmjTlcvVe@muUn/@@Rvnn50nC20yjXaBu892lIWiShnWfX8xbgab@brBEh6Xa5Teqye/UNv@Wtg@U/6Fu@zt08ZHv1bjQr2SzNsPeX84thf1gjA5jtc8nJv2@Tf/8/VqZoVRBMFj0a9OnmpKn16L5qX2K@mmcT/YbXS7JaqvJm9krvaj9adDzlNcLpsSALwvtT1XvB@HTHl6rmRG0HvDh3/qMULbM2geajVs5zNBOzFdZm3RnX81abH/ZCVDMUHaP/ob3z6B@m3WTTdBJxRUa9vyWB@plU1wHM1Nvna1Q4AdBNaj/qX4wfkWHPez1st7/tdlN0/7xeGQRSST2WEwoxx4XhDJjmDXmLQ2NERCSENF@cRJx@EqMSUkSGRNCgiAph6/YGiG6r4jQxKbH1Dqj1Dp5m8BIklgnl9ZIbiNtaQlvEYnBpAIoQTEOebG0kRTSE94VEySKgbUEEtw64xAiYwgBLizuGuOEpkBXWoIyspFMADPQJYRWLAkBpQ1QBMWAmc0zVXgnpAAlItCFn3qPwSRQTIZdHiWMAmsKCa6/uOvWvAnLk8ObkDZSOjxpq0QOFqbp0sPUjt/CJkTCqEKIlADLoWkprDOCSfPQSh7DVwTyhCBBGFouKe0kMCa1xjmZcaZEMhufso4KI3H8FY5De/LLNCLQg0EeA/05gIvTNAS07hRgMBTbcwzTd5soQBazgrCsHNiGstuh6DQ@5oYJInHQOAG6KSREbqNotyDnFZRu5UEyAZKlEJLCwUnAc3sZQ4KEEYUAK0BjBlWStJOOw@GEECJgv8TpQjnsLAVYEXZtmsZSMF804@d9lh15fh6008U53T8GmKbTWtKOi1MphJquzRBuRICeTroQboSfrle4c3AzAnR3ADFMLAE811icdP2d7y5Mu82PTvtC5dfjF7B8bl/cgVPnBNap7OiaiYFmHG4yjOyMJO@quCuM4H7OcxDJkR2L95c/) ; [1,std](https://tio.run/##XVRdU@M6DP0rmczsnXjjGttxnK@azs69j@0DFHjh8pCl7ZJ@pDR12ZYOv73rWG4D@wAisqRzdCQxL9/K3nyyOJ2q1eu60d7cOMhOV0vyvahqPW1m5fPUGx23utTVs/e2ribeqqzqYKybqv71@FSi41vZeDNVPvKnNsWrVT397Y1fTLmgfGRPCFeK4iWe40VRzYK6T1Ez1bumLobVVvf/W@9@LqfXQ8jS5fMiQFjjBt@qId7he/N7bH4e1LCYrZugBdvm5SN9ItvXZaUDH/sIDUk5mQRtBSgXbBEqlmpIttX7NECF4dRng2VeF4ZLMbEx3kplGR6pFd7gG7zHB/xuXo4tiP5CZq8Oam7S5v26QNoiDcmvqQ6qcB6GBqhNWbQIfEDzui/ooL5iPK@vOMVztVALg83yBd7Zsj@apjy0rQca4eYzUjHv9a5pgY6NBdmof9fL5fRZV@t6S1ZGdG3A4O3m61u5t2@tvNcCHTVppqv12zTYoOLy9w0qPj7OEt7lGu1DdVfsrwxBkzSoe/z7ohVoFuz7K3RcqX1xq5riXu2KL2mHUAXv6q63R9/fi4MalfqFbDdm2IerhaVw6I/QcaQOxdikP7TpH79fKjOUKgz7y15t@lQz8vxSNj90QFEvS4rxYaunK7LeafJq9kov62AW@p7y/HBGDPiq1MFM@d8In/l4o@ZG0LrPB3/rM0T5Km8faD5q5TBDOzNf523SvX01a7H7aSdAMUP5A/obPriABm3WbT5GZxXXaOAHLQ/k5zNch3NTb5OvURiEYdWv/6m@MX5NBz72/Nz/vza7ado/nU4sJqnEHksI5djjglBmDLPGvGWRMQJCUiLaL05iDl@pMRlJY2MiSBAk4/CVWCNE9xUTmtr0hFpnnFknbxMYSVPr5NIayW2kLS3hLSYJmEwAJSjGIS@RNpJCesq7YoLECbCWQIJbZxJBZAIhwIUlXWOc0AzoSktQxjaSCWAGukTQiiUhoLQBiqEYMLN5pgrvhBSgRAy68HPvCZgUismoy6OEUWBNIcH1l3TdmjdheXJ4E9JGSocnbZXYwcI0XXqU2fFb2JRIGFUEkRJgOTQthXXGMGkeWckT@IpBnggkiCLLJaOdBMZk1jgnM86MSGbjM9ZRYSRJPsNxaE9@mkYMejDIY6A/B3BxnoaA1p0CDIZie05g@m4TBchiVhCWlQPbSHY7FJ/Hx9wwQSQOGqdAN4OE2G0U7RbksoLSrTxIJkCyDEIyODgJeG4vE0iQMKIIYAVozKBKmnXScTicCEIE7Jc4XyiHnaUAK6KuTdNYBuaTZvyyz7Ijzy@Ddro4p/vHANN0WkvacXEqRVDTtRnBjQjQ00kXwY3w8/UKdw5uRoDuDiCBiaWA5xpL0q6/y91FWbf58XlfqPx8/AKWz@2LO3DqnMA6kx1dMzHQjMNNRrGdkeRdFXeFMdzPZQ4iPbHTVk/@AA) ; [-1,either](https://tio.run/##XVRdU@M6DP0rmc7snZi4xnYc56ums3PvY/sABV64PGQhhfQjpanLtnT47V3HchvYBxCRJZ2jI4lZ8V70Z8/z47Favq0a7c2Mg2x1tSAXeVXrspkWT6U3Pmx0oasn731VPXvLoqr9iW6q@uXhsUCH96Lxpqp44I9tileruvztTV5NOb94YI8IV4riBZ7heV5N/XpAUVPqbVPno2qjB/@ttr8W5dUIsnTxNPcR1rjBN2qEt/jO/J6Yn3s1yqerxm/BNlnxQB/J5m1Rab@HewiNSPH87LcVoJy/QShfqBHZVB@lj3LDacCGi6zODZf82cZ4S5WmeKyWeI2v8Q7v8Yd5ObQg@huZndqrmUmbDeocaYs0Ii@l9qtgFgQGqE2Ztwh8SLN6IOiwvmQ8qy85xTM1V3ODzbI53tqyP5um2Let@xrh5itSPuv3r2iODo0FWat/V4tF@aSrVb0hSyO6NmDwdv39rdjZt1beK4EOmjTlcvVe@muUn/@@Rvnn50nC20yjXaBu892lIWiShnWfX8xbgab@brBEh6Xa5Teqye/UNv@Wtg@U/6Fu@zt08ZHv1bjQr2SzNsPeX84thf1gjA5jtc8nJv2@Tf/8/VqZoVRBMFj0a9OnmpKn16L5qX2K@mmcT/YbXS7JaqvJm9krvaj9adDzlNcLpsSALwvtT1XvB@HTHl6rmRG0HvDh3/qMULbM2geajVs5zNBOzFdZm3RnX81abH/ZCVDMUHaP/ob3z6B@m3WTTdBJxRUa9vyWB@plU1wHM1Nvna1Q4AdBNaj/qX4wfkWHPez1st7/tdlN0/7xeGQRSST2WEwoxx4XhDJjmDXmLQ2NERCSENF@cRJx@EqMSUkSGRNCgiAph6/YGiG6r4jQxKbH1Dqj1Dp5m8BIklgnl9ZIbiNtaQlvEYnBpAIoQTEOebG0kRTSE94VEySKgbUEEtw64xAiYwgBLizuGuOEpkBXWoIyspFMADPQJYRWLAkBpQ1QBMWAmc0zVXgnpAAlItCFn3qPwSRQTIZdHiWMAmsKCa6/uOvWvAnLk8ObkDZSOjxpq0QOFqbp0sPUjt/CJkTCqEKIlADLoWkprDOCSfPQSh7DVwTyhCBBGFouKe0kMCa1xjmZcaZEMhufso4KI3H8FY5De/LLNCLQg0EeA/05gIvTNAS07hRgMBTbcwzTd5soQBazgrCsHNiGstuh6DQ@5oYJInHQOAG6KSREbqNotyDnFZRu5UEyAZKlEJLCwUnAc3sZQ4KEEYUAK0BjBlWStJOOw@GEECJgv8TpQjnsLAVYEXZtmsZSMF804@d9lh15fh6008U53T8GmKbTWtKOi1MphJquzRBuRICeTroQboSfrle4c3AzAnR3ADFMLAE811icdP2d7y5Mu82PTvtC5dfjF7B8bl/cgVPnBNap7OiaiYFmHG4yjOyMJO@quCuM4H7OcxDJsc@OxfvLHw).

Here is the same as function with somewhat flexible I/O and without validating (still **<s>776</s> <s>739</s> <s>719</s> 705 bytes**..):

```java
import java.util.*;(L,n,f)->{int i=0,l=L.size(),j,k;List<Double>t,r,R=new Stack(),u,U=R,S=R,V=R;n=n<1?l:n;double m=99,M=m,q,Q,x,y,z;do{for(t=new Stack(),x=y=j=0;j<n;)t.add(L.get(i+j++));for(k=n<12?0:n<40?n/12:n/20,j=k=k<1?1:k,u=new ArrayList(t),r=new Stack();j-->0;){r.add(q=Collections.min(t));r.add(Q=Collections.max(t));if(n>4){t.remove(q);t.remove(Q);}}for(var T:t)x+=T;x/=k=n>4?n-2*k:n;if(x<m){m=x;R=r;U=u;}for(var T:t)y+=(z=T-x)*z;y=Math.sqrt(y/k);if(y<M){M=y;S=r;V=u;}}while(i++<l-n);j=f.charAt(0)-97;System.out.println(f+" = "+f.format(f="%.2f",q=j<1?n<2?Collections.min(L):m:n<2?0:M));for(var o:j<1?U:n<2?L.subList(0,1):V)System.out.print(f.format((j<1?R:S).remove(o)?"(%.2f)":f,n+j<2?q:o)+" ");}
```

-20 bytes thanks to *@ceilingcat*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##tVZbT@s4EH7nV1iVVopPXeM4jnOrQUe7j@Voub6s9iG0KaSXBFKX01Lx21nH4zbt0Ur7wiKB8Xgu33zzTWGWv@WD2WT@WS5f6kajmbnTtS4X9FuGzNf5OfozN/Z6ivRzgR63uhiM63Wlkdf3E3w2XuSrFbrKy2p3hlBZ6aKZ5uMC/WivCL3V5QSNvVG50sM/6vXjorhAI9L6oYqgW92U1ROa4sw4f5yZHyud63KMfqAKKfTpjUhFpnhwsWsDSsXIQo3oqnwvPExmZJ4d59WkITeqKn6atPl4bjzW5F7dkFvz/aBuskpVQ/9ykVbZxAagpUoScqWW5JVckw3ZknfzspvWjadP0mzUVs0Uy2bDKsOa5pOJN6JPhfbK/qzfxzhrQ@Ztdn7J0moo2GV17vO0OueMzNRczU1dP52TtU37vWnybQvc05g0x5Wy2WBwwTK8a2yRV/V7vVgUY13W1Youy8oE4Azerk/f8o19K6dedSHwTtOmWNZvhfeKs8Pv1zj7@GihvuUNuks13vTVXbY5NwBN0GU14N/mhhyTYzNc4t1SbbIb1WT3ap2dhG37yntXd4MN/vaebdVVrp/p6rXR3vZ8biFsh1d4d6W22a0Jf2jDP34@l4vC8NUfLgaV6VNN6fg5b75rj@FBEmW325UulrRea/piJKEXlTft94wEev0pNcWXufamqvcb5dMeeVUzQ2g15Je/8jPC6TJtH1h65ebSoq7TNuDevhj5rB8t@4z4OH3Av5b2DgW9NuomvcV7Bmt82fNaDLiXTknVn5l8r2mNDdKeIfczaxX8YrRlFOyEbPW/NNvhgdb/@jvHsBknK6GLlW4NpuNTiXTraG0rmq@s3Q9pLAnyI8o4QVxQ5pvDt4d5SwJzCHCJqWhvnIYcbrE5EhqH5gggQNCEwy2yhxDdLaQstuERs8YwsUbeBvg0jq2RS3tIbj1taglvIY3gSARAgmQc4iJpPRmEx7xLJmgYAWoJILg1RgF4RuACWPyoa4xTlgBcaQHK0Hr6ApABLwG0YkEISG0KhZAMkNk4k4V3RApgIgRe@L73CI4Yksmgi2PUZ4CaQYDrL@q6NW/C4uTwJqT1lK6etFlCVxam6cKDxI7flo2phFEF4CmhLIempbDGECbNA0t5BLcQ6AmAgiCwWBLWUWCOxB7O6BtjQqVv/RO/g@LTKDoux6E9eTSNEPjwIc4H/jkUF/tpCGjdMeDDUGzPEUzfKVEALUaCIFYOaAPZaSjcj893wwSSOHAcA9wEAkKnKNYJ5CBB6SQPlAmgLAGXBBZOQj2nywgCJIwogLICOPYhS5x01HFYnABcBOhL7DeUg2YZlBVB16ZpLIHjiDN@0LPswPPDoB0vzug@GGCajmvJOiyOpQByujYD2BEBfDrqAtgRvt9e4dbBzQiquwWIYGIx1HONRXHX32HvgqRTfrjXC5PHyy9AfE4vbsGZMwLqRHZwzcSAMw47GYR2RpJ3WdwWhrA/hzmI2PxJObOf3RUde/uPbIJMyV7@9tSz/8Ug9C9/y/7z5TShz/@XjCs9@bqM7KsT@l/e8zHCj7OPz38A)

**Explanation:**

```java
import java.util.*;           // Required import for List, Stack and Collections
interface M{                  //  Class
  static void main(String[]a){//   Mandatory main-method
    var f=a[2];               //    Save the third argument in String `f`
    int n=new Short(a[1]),    //    Save the second argument as integer in `n`
        i=0,l,j,k;            //    Some temp/index integers
    if(n<0)return;            //    If `n` is negative: stop the program
    List<Double>L=new Stack(),//    Input-List, starting empty
                t,r,R=L,u,U=L,S=L,V=L;
                              //    Some temp Lists
    for(var s:a[0].split(","))//    Loop over the input-items as Strings
      L.add(new Double(s));   //     Convert them to doubles, and add them to the List
    l=L.size();               //    Set `l` to the amount of items
    n=n<1?l:n;                //    If `n` was 0, make it equal to `l` instead
    double m=99,M=m,          //    Lowest `avg` and `std`, both starting at 99
           q,Q,x,y,z;         //    Some temp floats
    do{                       //    Start the do-while:
      for(t=new Stack(),      //     Reset List `t`
          x=y=j=0;j<n;)       //     Loop `j` in the range [0, `n`):
        t.add(L.get(i+j++));  //      And add the items on index `i+j` of List `L` to `t`
      for(k=n<12?             //     If `n` is smaller than 12
             0                //      Set `k` to 0
            :n<40?            //     Else-if `n` is in the range [12; 40)
             n/12             //      Set `k` to 1/12th of `n`
            :                 //     Else (`n` is 40 or larger)
             n/20,            //      Set `k` to 1/20th of `n`
          j=k=k<1?1:k,        //     If `k` is 0 due to rounding, make it 1 instead
          u=new ArrayList(t), //     Copy List `t` to `u`
          r=new Stack();      //     And reset List `r`
          j-->0;){            //     Loop `k` amount of times:
        r.add(q=Collections.min(t));
                              //      Add the smallest item in List `t` to `r`
        r.add(Q=Collections.max(t));
                              //      as well as the largest item
        if(n>4){              //      If `n` is 5 or larger:
          t.remove(q);t.remove(Q);}}
                              //       Remove those two items from List `t`
      for(var T:t)            //     Loop over List `t`:
        x+=T;                 //      And sum them all into value `x`
      x/=k=n>4?               //     If `n` is 5 or larger
          n-2*k               //      Set `k` to `n-2*k` and divide `x` by that
         :                    //     Else:
          n;                  //      Set `k` to `n` and divide `x` by that
      if(x<m){                //     If `x` is smaller than the previous smallest avg `m`
        m=x;                  //      Replace `m` with `x` (smallest avg)
        R=r;                  //      Replace `R` with `r` (items between parenthesis)
        U=u;}                 //      And replace `U` with `u` (all `n` items in this avg) 
      for(var T:t)            //     Loop over List `t` again:
        y+=(z=T-x)*z;         //      And sum `(T-x)**2` to `y`
      y=Math.sqrt(y/k);       //     Also divide `y` by `k`, and take its square-root
                              //     The process above is how you calculate the std
      if(y<M){                //     If `y` is smaller than the previous smallest std `M`:
        M=y;                  //      Replace `M` with `y` (smallest std)
        S=r;                  //      Replace `S` with `r` (items between parenthesis)
        V=u;}}                //      And replace `V` with `u` (all `n` items in this std)
    while(i++<l-n);           //    Continue the do-while as long as `i` is smaller than `l-n`
    j=f.charAt(0)-97;         //    Set `j` to the alphabetic index of the first letter of `f`
    System.out.println(f+" = "//    Print "`f` = "
      +f.format(f="%.2f",     //     Round to two decimals
        q=j<1?                //     If it's an avg:
           n<2?               //      And `n` is 1:
            Collections.min(L)//       Simply take the smallest value in `L`
           :                  //      Else:
            m                 //       Take the calculated lowest avg `m`
          :                   //     Else (it's an std):
           n<2?               //      If `n` is 1:
            0                 //       Use 0
           :                  //      Else:
            M));              //       Take the calculated lowest std `M`
    i=0;                      //    Reset `i` to 0
    for(var o:j<1?            //    If it's an avg:
               U              //     Loop over List `U`
              :               //    Else (it's an std instead):
               n<2?           //     If `n` is 1:
                L.subList(0,1)//      Only take the first item of List `L`
               :              //     Else:
                V)            //      Loop over List `V`
      System.out.print(f.format(
       (j<1?                   //    If it's an avg:
         R                     //     Use List `R`
        :                      //    Else (it's an std instead):
         S)                    //     Use List `S`
           .remove(o)?         //    If the current item is in this List:
             "(%.2f)"          //     Round to two decimals, and add parenthesis
            :                  //    Else:
             f,                //     Only round to two decimals
       n+j<2?                  //    If it's an avg, and `n` is 1:
        q                      //     Take the smallest value in `L`
       :                       //    Else:
        o)                     //     Take the current item in this loop
          +(++i<n              //    If it's not the last item,
                 &i%12>0?      //    and also not the 12th item of the row:
            ", "               //     Append a comma and space as separator
           :                   //    Else:
            "\n"));}}          //     Append a newline instead
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), score: 85.5 (114 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) - 25% bonus)

<sup>† Could be **score: 83.25 (111 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) - 25% bonus)** by removing `2.ò` (which rounds the output avg/std to 2 decimals). This isn't mentioned in the challenge rules, but since everything else about the I/O is so strict and rounding to two decimals is also done by the WCA (World Cube Association), I've just included it.</sup>

```
DŒsgI‚²ĀèDUùεƵJü2XŽ4Ý2ô@ÏXšzX*òθFDWsà‚vyD…(ÿ).;}}Dʒ'(å≠X5‹~}žuмDÅA©-nÅAt®‚³Çθè‚}Σθ}|θÇнƵ7.Sè`2.ò³'=‚sªs12ô»»¹gÝ²å×
```

Also supports `low` vs `high` as fourth input. At the cost of just 8 bytes (`|θÇнƵ7.Sè` instead of `н`), this was well worth the 25% bonus.
Outputs an empty string for invalid \$n\$.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##TVRNa5NBEL73V/TWKs2yOzv7hQgKQdCriAERrCBFKO0hWmkxkosUT0IvglBQpFI9eEgttNgqvGt68BD6G/JH4nafTTb0MN155@OZ55nJZnf16fNnk0l7uNdduzvuf2wGf/vxsP0gno6OL47vxTPqDM857lP8eSu@7ww/73Sux8Ho5E77YTd@Sglb2@1x/@ty/HNN3Oj12v/2lpbjwfjdp44Z90/f9Ia/X16etePb28231kYyL5ofV12O4u7oJB6mf3ujL6OT3uv02r08vzh24n48fEIiDpqjpZvpe7f53lWpe/Mr/Z2uxf1mEA/ih8nkkTLC25VF5YSklUViIVUyKpv0LehkGCFe8NWLhCG8fDJBeJOMRgKLQHi5bJjrywjpc7qT2WlCdtJVghLeZyfZbCzlyFza4psRDiYwIKEYIc/ZHCmR7qkWY2EcUFuAoOx0GpEOIcCiXB2MhAyAazNAa3KkYiADLxqjZBCM0qmRQTEgy3mpClUiGUwY8ELT2R2MRzGra54USgK1REKZz9Vp0zfOOAnf2OZIW/rZXMWUtlCzpOuQ5c9tvbCQSiPSoi1haMvZaaA06Uy5w8uAHg0KtM5YgqwUJBOyKU6VnEFYleODqlCUcG6@HWE8O6eGAR8KeQr8E5rzVA3G6IUBBVHyzA7ql01k0JJWEMtKQKtt3SEzlU8VMUESgWMPuAEJpmyUrAsyW0FbVh6UMSgLCAk4OIt@ZS8dEiwk0mjL4Fihig@VOsLhaIQw9ounF0rYWYm2rOuYabAAM8cZzfbZVvA0E7rwUpzlhwFqFq6trFgKSxo1y5gaN8Lgs1CncSM0vV4u51A0QvdyAA6KefQrgzlf55vdnQ518810X6SdP37G8pV9KQcuixOog61wk2LgjHCT2mSNLNUq5QoN7memA/vHC3phdWttYX3z1aTV2thsra/ubP8H) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##bVRdS5RBFL73Vyx7o8XuMHPm651CLFiCuukiIkEEjWIVRINVQ2HDG4uuAm@CQDDCsC4KFg0lLdhJLwoWf4N/ZBvnmd1ZP9iLw5z3fDznec7Zhcb009nn3eV2q3x//sXSYuNWqTy2Mvrv9VD54dJicIR3pVs73mjU29@nTo/O1j5E@2fN79Qe@4PO3sneA39I48dHym@S373j340ff1wdv@lbnf17tScNvxVylldqZ2ufR/zvG@x2s1n7uzE84rfP3m6N67O1g1fN419Lp4c1v363/aU6H8xi@xsa@fWGf9PZ9zvh2ex86uw3gzO835wenexZ9sjvTBHzLUQOj4aoRvtrQwQc7Z/h16r7zQjXb/v33Ur7x1h7tzsxISvl6eV6uVKeW3hZnqxMCLrG0Vh8lh380pu4uJxy9X0ho3q5R3l2fnl6bvY8ZNBfyuhmZuszF@ENelC95@GXHQMI@1nXOC4mVa90uoISHyaHJoRmhamUhGWcKiVSLDQskYgmfHMyGIWQgqnzFzFNeBXBOFboYCQSFHOEl41GqfzSjBcx3fLo1C466TxBsKKITjLRGIqRsbTBN80sjFOAhGKEPGtiJEd6QbmYYtoCtQEIik4rEWkRAizC5sGIcQe4JgI0OkYKBWTgRWKUCEKhdGikUQzIYl6oQplIBSY0eKHe7BamQDEjcx5nggM1R0Kaz@ZpwzcVcRK@KRMjTepnYhWd2kLNlC5dlD@2LZiBVBKRBm0JQxsVnRpKk4yUW7w06JGgQMqIxfFMQTAumuQUwemYETHeiQxFMGsH2xHGMwNqaPAhkCfAP6G56qmhMHpiQECUOLOF@mkTFWgJK4hlJaCVJu@Q7sknkpggicBxAbgOCTptFM8L0l9Bk1YelClQ5hDicHAG/dJeWiQYSCTRVoFjgSqFy9QRDkciRGG/VO9CCTvL0VbJPGYYzMEMcEb9fTYZPPWFTrwkZ/pjgJqJa8MzlsSSRM00psSNKPCZqJO4Eepdr0rnkDRC93QAFooV6JcGs0Wer3930uXN17194Wbw@BWWL@1LOnCenEDtTIYbFANnhJuUOmpkKFdJV6hxP30dVDHZrVbnF6pz06sr/wE).

**Explanation:**

```python
D                    # Duplicate the first (implicit) input-list
 Œ                   # Pop the copy, and get all its sublists
  sgI‚²Āè            # Transform n=0 to n=listLength
  s                  #  Swap so the first input-list is at the top again
   g                 #  Pop and push its length
    I‚               #  Pair it with the second input-integer `n`
      ²              #  Push the second input-integer `n` again
       Ā             #  Check whether it's NOT 0 (0 if 0; 1 otherwise)
        è            #  0-base index this into the pair
         DU          # Store a copy in variable `X`
           ù         # Only keep the subslist of that size
ε                    # Map over each sublist
 ƵJü2XŽ4Ý2ô@ÏXšzX*òθ #  Determine how many lowest/highest numbers we should surround
                     #  with parenthesis:
 ƵJ                  #   Push compressed integer 120
   ü2                #   Get its overlapping pairs: [12,20]
     X               #   Push value `X`
      Ž4Ý            #   Push compressed integer 1240
         2ô          #   Split it into pairs: [12,40]
           @         #   >= check on `X`: [X>=12,X>=40]
            Ï        #   Keep the [12,20]-values at the truthy indices
             Xš      #   Prepend `X` itself to this list
               z     #   Calculate 1/v for each value in this list
                X*   #   Multiply each by `X`
                  ò  #   Round each to the nearest integer
                   θ #   Pop and keep the last one
 F                   #  Loop that many times:
  D                  #   Duplicate the current sublist
   W                 #   Push its minimum (without popping)
                     #   (will ignore values already wrapped in parenthesis)
    s                #   Swap so the copy of the sublist is at the top again
     à               #   Pop and push its maximum
                     #   (will ignore values already wrapped in parenthesis)
      ‚              #   Pair this minimum and maximum together
       v             #   Loop over this pair:
        yD           #    Push the min or max twice
          …(ÿ)       #    Surround the top copy in parenthesis
              .;     #    Replace the first occurrence of this value in the sublist
       }             #   Close the [min,max]-loop
 }                   #  Close the other loop
  D                  #  Duplicate the modified sublist
   ʒ                 #  Filter the copy by:
    '(å≠            '#   Check that the current value does NOT contain parenthesis
           ~         #   OR
        X5‹          #   Whether `X` is smaller than 5
   }                 #  Close the filter
    žu               #  Push constant string "()<>[]{}"
      м              #  Remove all those characters from each value within the list
                     #  (only applies if `X` is smaller than 5)
  DÅA©-nÅAt®‚        #  Pop this list, and push its [std,avg] pair:
  D                  #   Duplicate this list
   ÅA                #   Pop the copy, and get its average
     ©               #   Store this average in variable `®` (without popping)
      -              #   Subtract this average from each value in the list
       n             #   Square each
        ÅA           #   Take the average of this list again
          t          #   Take the square-root of that
           ®‚        #   And pair this std with the average `®`
  ³                  #  Push the third input-string
   Ç                 #  Convert it to a list of codepoint integers
                     #  ("avg"=[97,118,103]; "std"=[115,116,100])
    θ                #  Pop and push the last value ("avg"=103; "std"=100)
     è               #  Use that to 0-based modular index into the pair of [std,avg]
      ‚              #  And pair it together with the modified list
}                    # Close the map
 Σ                   # Sort this list by:
  θ                  #  The last item of the pair (the avg or std)
 }                   # Close the sort-by
  |                  # Get a list of all remaining inputs: [third,fourth]
   θ                 # Pop and keep its last item (the fourth input)
                     # (`|θ` cannot be `I`, since `³` won't add the third input to the
                     # input history)
    Ç                # Convert it to a list of codepoint integers as well
                     # ("low"=[108,111,119]; "high"=[104,105,103,104])
     н               # Pop and push the first value ("low"=108; "high"=104)
      Ƶ7             # Push compressed integer 108
        .S           # Compare: -1 if <108; 0 if ==108; 1 if >108
                     # (aka "low"=0; "high"=-1)
          è          # Use that to 0-based modular index into the sorted list
                     # (where -1 will take the last/highest item)
`                    # Pop the pair and push its contents to the stack
 2.ò                 # Round the avg/std to 2 decimals†
    ³                # Push the third input-string again
     '=‚            '# Pair it with an "="
        sª           # Swap and append the rounded avg/std
 s                   # Swap so the list is at the top
  12ô                # Split it into parts of size 12
     »               # Join each inner list by spaces, and then each string by newlines
          »          # Join the two strings on the stack with newline delimiter
¹gÝ²å×               # Transform it to an empty string if `n` is invalid:
¹g                   #  Push the length of the first input-list
  Ý                  #  Pop and push a list in the range [0,listLength]
   ²å                #  Check if the second input `n` is in this list
                     #  (1 if truthy; 0 if falsey)
     ×               #  Repeat the string that many times
                     # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to compress large integers?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `ƵJ` is `120`; `Ž4Ý` is `1240`; and `Ƶ7` is `108`.