# Best Rolling Ao5

Tags: code-golf, array, floating-point

In speedcubing, an Ao5 (Average of 5) is computed for a set of five times by removing the fastest and slowest times, and then computing the mean of the remaining three times.

A "rolling ao5" is computed for a sequence of at least five times by computing the ao5 for every  set of consecutive five times (some sets will overlap). The best rolling ao5 is the lowest time out of all of these.

Related very old and much more involved question: [Calculate the average and standard deviation, rubiks cube style](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65806/calculate-the-average-and-standard-deviation-rubiks-cube-style)

### Input

An array of between 5 and 100 times inclusive, where each time is a number with exactly two decimal places, between 0.01 and 60.00. The array may be given as input in any reasonable format (list, csv string, etc.)

### Output

The best rolling Ao5, where the mean must be rounded to the nearest hundredth and outputted with exactly two decimal places (including trailing zeros).

### Test cases

Input on first line, output on second line.

```
7.16 5.04 4.67 6.55 4.99
5.53
```

```
10.00 10.00 10.00 10.00 10.00 7.00 6.00
9.00
```

```
34.87 33.24 33.31 33.63 27.04 29.14 29.74 31.65 27.42 30.13 28.31 32.50 32.61 36.38 28.60 33.85 28.42 36.00 32.41 35.35 29.47 31.02 28.87 35.08
28.77
```

Comment: Nice challenge, except that the strict output format is a bit annoying :-/

Comment: Can we take the length of the array as an additional input?

Comment: @Delfad0r no (well I don't think that is standard I/O)

Comment: @qwr, it is. In order to not disadvantage languages that have no native way of determining the length.

Comment: whatever the standard is for array input challenges

Comment: I'm still not quite sure what "best rolling ao5" is expected to do. I also tried to search it on Google, but it only yield this post and its sandbox. Could you give an example about how to calculate it, or define it as some math formal syntax?

Comment: I would add/change some test cases, as the best rolling Ao5 in all of them are just the first 5 elements.

Comment: Yes you're right. I'll add more tests cases or better ones

Comment: ok I changed the test cases to be more interesting. lmk if you have any other good test cases

Comment: If you remove the fastest and slowest time from `[10.00, 10.00, 10.00, 10.00, 10.00]` what do you get? `[10.00, 10.00, 10.00]` or `[]`?

Answer (score 5):

## R, <s>93</s> <s>88</s> <s>86</s> <s>80</s> <s>79</s> 77 bytes

Simple reference solution. Uses `trim` feature of `min` as Giuseppe pointed out.

```
x=scan()
sprintf("%.2f",min(sapply(5:sum(x|1),function(i)mean(x[i-0:4],.2))))
```

-2 bytes by Giuseppe by replacing `length(x)` and cleaning up unnecessary character in sprintf.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYtBCsMgEADv@4yUwgpmWYMaEuhLQg8hVBCqlZiAhf7deOmc5jCz1/LI2xpRwEjKgiHWoMmOYMmYZtMEiokZ6u0f5rT7eDjs7jS4TgYfMa8pvb9o5nwGLD8lpDvjdvhPRC/Cq21l8T3P@ilpEI1aLw)

### <s>80</s> 78 bytes

Similar answer but with a for loop.

```
x=scan()
a={}
for(i in 5:sum(x|1))a=min(a,mean(x[i-0:4],.2))
sprintf("%.2f",a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcqxCsIwEADQ/b6itAg5iEdakpQW8iXicEijAXtK2iEgfnvs4vaGl2sJ241FIYzUe3BkLFjyI3hy7tA0QW/IGKjdP3L4fCG@skpNksbNz0Xu@0MVRA5rEsV6XY5YLulsZnvVNCDC9s5J9qjaU0dDbDVjrT8)

Comment: [77 bytes](https://tio.run/##DctBCsMgEEDRvccIFEawwxjUkJSepHQRQoWBOpWYgIXe3fpXb/P31uq9bKuAvpW8sxwRhguOcTCJBcqa8/sLfilngvqz2sRTtoM/AqzTq2/1wVda3NPgqHttQhuUR3LKYZhUQO@75llZQqL2Bw)

Answer (score 5):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 72 bytes

```
[ 5 clump [ 3 [1,b] [ < ] kth-objects mean ] map infimum "%.2f"sprintf ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVC7TsNAEOzzFaNIdLC6t22goEM0NIgqSuFYdnJJ/MA@VyjfbnZNgUQzmp2Zfdw1ZZX6cfn8eHt/fUTTj22ZUuyOOI79PAiJPS712NVXsHVagcayO9bTL59SmeKUYjVhqr/muqvYedpsvpGRDvCkHByFDIG8Z1YUuLGpNSkFrf5j8UclZgqyGSyP8jCeQgHjyCrRcwfrKGfXknGCVgsGC5PJVs7oFQO7moIX3RlYRZoz@Zo35JVgYB7I5qIHJXPydWOhRJGuIDdx0nHSk/Uy2WUyWRnJyCX82hy3ZQeP6jq3A3aw2On7w57ZM/a4pNNDfzjXVeLvq8uOpbYcELsmtnOL7R2ZZjsNY@xSg/2SxvjCnWvNUSmXHw)

### Explanation:

It's a quotation (anonymous function) that takes a sequence of numbers from the data stack as input and leaves a string on the data stack as output.

- `5 clump` Split a sequence into groups of 5 with overlapping. This is the 'rolling' part.
- `[ ... ] map` Apply a quotation to each element of a sequence, collecting the results into a sequence of the same size.
- `3 [1,b] [ < ] kth-objects` Take the second, third, and fourth elements of a sequence (from a sorted standpoint). This is shorter than trying to sort it and then chop off both ends.
- `mean` Take the mean.
- `infimum` Take the smallest element from a sequence.
- `"%.2f"sprintf` Return the result as a string rounded to two decimal places.

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>86</s> 82 bytes

```r
function(x,l=sum(x|1))sprintf("%.2f",min(apply(matrix(x,l+1,5),1,mean,.2)[5:l-5]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7BasQwDETv/gqzULCpV0i25ThL@yWlh7DUENi4IclCCv331Mqpl0GMnkazHEW/XY/yrPdt/K5md4/39TmZ/ZesXedlrFsxlxfw5eKmsZphnh8/Zhq2ZdwFfiXH1pGbvobqwNsPvj2u/GntUQzdCK0qZr0P1VirfA@h06EDYu0ZUq99hIC6@TnqECG3bQAfRQOJpqB9BxiFoVNT2xIkFj96HRCoMfnkPTCKpjYnCFn8hJKTz489iiNXCfAkYyMZAkty7CQZvTDShAGz@le/9U6qmVFFSJ1KwNymvleELe34Aw)

R's `mean` function helpfully can be used to calculate a trimmed mean.

Outgolfed by [qwr](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224484/67312).

Comment: You can replace `trim` with `t`. Actually you might be able to get rid of the named argument entirely

Comment: A bit embarrassing to be outgolfed by the reference implementation! I'll edit in a bit, on mobile atm

Comment: Only when I used the `trim` argument of `mean`

Comment: also can't you use `x=scan()` instead of a function? https://tio.run/##TY7BasQwDETv/gqzULCpV0i25ThL@yWlh7DUENi4IclCCv331Mqpl0GMnkazHEW/XY/yrPdt/K5md4/39TmZ/ZesXedlrFsxlxfw5eKmsZphnh8/Zhq2ZdwFfiXH1pGbvobqwNsPvj2u/GntUQzdCK0qZr0P1VirfA@h06EDYu0ZUq99hIC6@TnqECG3bQAfRQOJpqB9BxiFoVNT2xIkFj96HRCoMfnkPTCKpjYnCFn8hJKTz489iiNXCfAkYyMZAkty7CQZvTDShAGz@le/9U6qmVFFSJ1KwNymvleELe34Aw

Comment: Can you explain how you used matrix? I think it's because by default x is recycled to be filled in the matrix as l+1 length columns?

Comment: @qwr [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/154518/67312) has an explanation for an unrelated challenge. It is recycling as you suggest, though it necessitates the use of the indexing since the recycling will be "too long".

Comment: does rowMeans have a trim argument?

Comment: @qwr I did check just in case it had a `...` that gets passed on to other functions (like `apply` and the `*apply` functions), but alas, it does not.

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 20 bytes

```
5YCS6LY)YmX<'%.2f'YD
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/3zTSOdjMJ1IzMjfCRl1VzyhNPdLl//9ocz1DMwVTPQMTBRM9M3MFMz1TUyDL0jIWAA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##XY@9DsIwDIR3nsILqlgsx39JJDY6ssFAVVWChQk23r/YHRhYTqfzl7Pzfnxe63216XTx83SY3rfjsEd@DtO4jtd1rlgcDElB0Ss4moXrfdnNpSARFPrX/rMBcUepIFFjwIbegRWFIPKmIIotpoKsqVJSXYBrbgymbOoxLeiWuTIIYQmmbTyjUaqHd5SWuVP2tG1jp0zyleddQWqQhmLZrDWbiZPJS@KnW4PQ8gU).

#### Explanation

```
        % Implicit input
5YC     % Matrix with sliding blocks of length 5 as columns
S       % Sort each column
6L      % Push [2 1j-1]. When used as an index, this is interpreted as "2:end-1"
Y)      % Index the rows as specified. This removes first and last rows
Ym      % Mean of each column
X<      % Mininum
'%.2f'  % Push this string: format specification, 'sprintf'-style
YD      % Convert to string with specified format
        % Implicit display
```

Direct translation to an anonymous function in Octave (with the Image package):

```
@(x)sprintf('%.2f',min(mean(sort(im2col(x,[1 5]))(2:end-1,:))))
```

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 97 bytes

```javascript
f=a=>Math.min(([,x,y,z,q]=[a.pop(),...a.slice(-4)].sort((a,b)=>a-b),x+y+z)/3,q?f(a):z).toFixed(2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY8/b8IwEMV3PsWJBVuYq@N/SYpCp7K1S0fKYIIDqUISklABVT87tZHaocvT6d3P754/7Kft865sh1ndbN3tVmQ2W7zYYY@HsiZkxc7swq7suM5WFtumJZQhosW@KnNHZoqusW@6gRDLNjRb2NmGsvP0Mr3SB8mOTwWx9PFKcWiW5dltiaC3zh1PZefIpOgnFDtnt8uycm@XOic8gG9DV9Y7QrFvq3Ig4/d6TLFoumeb70kP2QK@RgCVG8BCBv0vBp462Ja8ng4b19G5Z/Km7pvKYdXsSCjizW86v8UYGdDIFSg0MRjU2k9pOooi5Bwi/l/Tv3EkUpQxSB@hQWg0KQiFkoP3EwVSYeK3EoUKKqOgRoKIwzXPRHc1fhuh0cFXAiTHyDPJnReoeVDjZ4MyCb7hISe5X0x5cMIrE1p5UnlSo9QhWcUhmYvAhCb@l8kP)

Comment: Nice, forgot about toFixed!

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 83 bytes

```
\.

\d+
$*
M!&`\b(1+,){4}1+
%(O`1+
^1+|,|1+$

)M`1{2,3}
O#`
1G`
+`^..?$
0$&
..$
.$&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU@7bgMxDNv1F0WdQ1ILguSHzp46ZgryA4fALdKhS4eiW5Jvv0o3dOhCExRNUd8fP59fb@tufxzrQgDLNUJ4gdPTNJb3vUQ83MpDIuz252HPReId7xIDwOE05JYwP@D8PECOA@K4EL0G4DABUQAK07rOJIqVuGAhnVGpVmO9gwgxo/B/7H8UUqc8Y7aIiqmSdkyFMqPprWAu1GyaKRXHLI6aMc2@zTyyodpUSKvrxfoyiXna5k9U2VGNK@XmurLntG1jZ1f8l3orcxZzVsrVk8vsyZzc403syvYL) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
\.
```

Multiply the input by 100.

```
\d+
$*
```

Convert to unary.

```
M!&`\b(1+,){4}1+
```

Extract all overlapping sets of five consecutive values.

```
%(`
)`
```

For each set, ...

```
O`1+
```

... sort in order, ...

```
^1+|,|1+$
```

... delete the fastest and slowest times, ...

```
M`1{2,3}
```

... and take the mean, rounding to nearest, converting to decimal.

```
O#`
```

Sort the means.

```
1G`
```

Take the fastest.

```
+`^..?$
0$&
..$
.$&
```

Divide it by 100.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>103</s>, <s>89</s>, <s>76</s>, 73 bytes

Saved **14 bytes** thanks to qwr!

Saved **7 bytes** thanks to okie's suggestion to use a list comprehension.

Saved another **6 bytes** by switching to a `lambda` function.

Saved **3 bytes** after removing the extra brackets and comma and fixing the first slice. Thanks to caird, okie, and att! Also removed a pair of extra parentheses.

```python
lambda t:"%.2f"%min(sum(sorted(t[i:i+5])[1:4])/3for i in range(len(t)-4))
```

The program iterates through all the consecutive runs of 5. The runs of 5 are `sorted` and the first and last elements are removed using slicing. The program `sum`s the values remaining in the run and divides by `3` to find the average. Finally, percent formatting is used return the `min` value.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HchBCoMwEEDRqwRBmNA21Zh0EehJUhcpxnZAR4njoqdPQzaPz99//N1I5/B85SWs7ykIdk2r9Ny0KxIc5wrHljhOwB4dXuwofe/MKO/DvCWBAkmkQJ8ISyRgeTNS5j0hMQRA2k8GWY7vVdddha4OyhZNbVt9FMc/)

Comment: rounding is not needed when using format specifier. And you can use x directly: https://tio.run/##DcRBCsMgEADAe16xBAIrtS0xpgfBl4gHoaZdaFYxm0NfbzuHqV95Fza9iyeup6Aakv@3lQYExNASvzJ@MqOoq1UuXfxx7niUJvmJEsitUYXZ2ajuix5qI5ZxupltnHZiTKr3MGswGhYNVsOq4RF/

Comment: Thank you! I am not very familiar with percent formatting. Also didn't realize that there was another `sorted` function.

Comment: Make a with comprehension list will save bytes: https://tio.run/##BcHBCoMwDADQ@74iCEICmcNaPQj7ktLDYHULzLTUeNjX1/fK375ZXWv2FC2nId1KFbWuH9zW9bsoBjzOHY9cLb3RgqxzpDCuPtJjYtpyBQFRqC/9JPwlRaO7p0ithZHBMUwMnmFmWOIF

Comment: I feel silly for not catching that! Thx!

Comment: You can remove the `[...]` brackets: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DchBCsMgEADAryyBwC7YlhjTg9CXWA@WmFaIq5jNoa@3nePUr3wK6x4ez76H/FoDiB3Gq96GMSdGPM6MR2kSVxSX7OLJTdZ4us2KttIgQWJogd8R98godDFEvbbEggET11OQ/uMmBVrBrMAoWBTc/Q8 "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Comment: `,` after 3 is not required

Comment: The first slice should be `i:i+5`, and the input needs to be floats (which is guaranteed by the spec) to work properly in python 2.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 25 bytes

```
ṡ5ṢṖḊƊ€ÆmṂ×ȷ2+.ḞDṙ-2;”.ṙ2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY8xSkVBDEX7v4r0Ysgkk7wZbF2D4AJs5LsAO/mFwl@AYqGgtZUIvsHygbiN@RsZk1dY2FwuN2duMpcX2@31GL29aG@vvd33ef@9P@zeltur3nbLw88nH2Gfn097ezzmk8PNE7rj0b8@@vx@ttyt9PkYEyYDRcqQ0SYwVHVX6yYlJIJE/7X@2Q1XlAnEKxRY0SpwRiHwvGSQjMWngpxDJYWaAE@xzZm0qvk0oWnkmUEIkzNl5RmVQs29oZTIjaKnrBsrRRKvLK5yMjupKBrNeYpm4mDiEv9l@QU)

Note to self: add formatting options to my new golfing language to avoid this ^ clownery

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 30 bytes

```
0j2":[:<./5(3%~1#.1 2 3{/:~)\]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZDNSkNBDIX3PsWhItdCm2Ymk8wPuhJcuXKrXYlFuvEBCn31a3K5Ci7mcDj5ksnMed7QdMLjwIQdGMPPnvD0@vI88zlvxtt4oIPey9013VJChlwO47p9P87bm8@Pr29MSioT9gMnVEoGJS4oZBVGqu56X8nExLyiKbnHkvzT/mfXptxIfptyJ6kQv0aRlawjF69G3gqkUPOqUC6hkkJNkGts5Exa1LyayDTy4u9hSs60hc@kHGrujaRFbhxz2nJj50iiy2JPJ4uTSqIxudSYzDmY2MR/os0/)

Answer (score 2):

## [V (vim)](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 140 bytes

```
o<esc>qq15wlh0y15wO<esc>pj0d3w@qqdk@qqt:s/ /\r/g
<c-o>:.,.4$sor n
:.,.4j
d3w$3bhd$:s/ /+/g
C<c-r>=(<c-r>")/3
<esc>k0@tq@t:%s/^\n
:sor n
{0C<c-r>=printf("%.2f",<c-r>")
<esc>o<esc>d}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY5dbsIwEITfcworChJVYbPx2o4T0ShSD9ALoD5ASilUhPwIVFU9e7rr8DJrzX4z3ts0tZuPYV91XWbv30f84fEWnOsJG7rXXdecWcZySFW67dPPaLNft1UJKzDJ0PbqEoX3KWI6od2xSQL6zOQro331sgwjfkopCs1nrMeuHsvFkL5vOT63/OIDv/Zfl/GwjBegD/HqkZ2T863N3zTpAihXlENmlbbgCqUNECr2vVFkwPOWQBtRykQdKZ0DGmGyoI63GTgrvtGKEDJmfOA1WBR1/HZAXnyH0uPDjwWKIykHGEjDpAWy0mxyaUYtjFxiAf20vv0D)

I was lucky that vim had `printf` for this challenge, I'd finished most of it before I realized the output spec (phew)

Comment: maybe vim can be shorter by working with the  values *100 and then inserting the decimal place at the end

Comment: i tried doing *100 and rounding but `printf` was shorter and simpler for the output format.

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 18 bytes

```python
2⍕2⌷⌊⌿3+/↑∧¨5,/⎕÷3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY8xTgNBDEX7PYV7iOOxx96Z40TaXZoIKCjgAhBFC1KKnCHcICUS3GQusthbUNB8fX2/@fbsHveb4WW3f7jbjM9P4/0wDks7vE0Lt/czt/na5mObv@Rm215P7XD5/tTbbfs4/1wluGXqekwGipQho/VgqOqu1m7qUkIiSPRf6591iCtKD@I1CqxoFTijEHheMkjG4lNBzqGSQk2A@9joTFrVfJrQNPLMIITJmbLyjEqh5t5QSuRG0VPWjZUiiVcWdzmZnVQUjebcRzNxMHGJ/7T8Ag)

Full program. Example with the second testcase:

`⎕÷3` input divided by 3:

```python
3.667 3.333 3.333 3.333 3.000 3.333
```

`5,/` groups of 5 adjacent values:

```python
┌─────────────────────────┬─────────────────────────┐
│3.667 3.333 3.333 3.333 3│3.333 3.333 3.333 3 3.333│
└─────────────────────────┴─────────────────────────┘
```

`↑∧¨` sort each group and arrange the result in a matrix:

```python
3 3.333 3.333 3.333 3.667
3 3.333 3.333 3.333 3.333
```

`3+/` in each row, take sums of 3 adjacent values:

```python
9.667 10 10.33
9.667 10 10
```

`⌊⌿` get the minimum for each column:

```python
9.667 10 10
```

`2⍕2⌷` select the second value and format with 2 decimal places:

```python
10.00
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 109 bytes

This doesn't work on Tio because their version of Pari/GP is apparently too old to have the vital function strsplit(). But it works as advertised on mine, version 2.13.0

```
A(s)=s=[eval(x)|x<-strsplit(s," ")];printf("%.2f",vecmin(vector(#s-4,i,vecsum(vecsort(s[i..i+4])[2..4])/3)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY/LagMxDEX3@QrhUrDpjOqnxqbNot8RsgglCYY8hvE0ZNF/T6UpdNHNlbg6vpLH3VT74/h4fOhm1m292d92J3033/f3vs1TG0911q1ToMz2bZzqZT5o9Yz@oLrb/vNcL5rLfJ30U@tjV8VsX2cx23Xil5uKWF/i1mw8IpfXYIxZyTo1oCNIaCNEpAEIU@KuFGVWPHUOrQVn/2v5a385XzAMEDgsgU9IBXzEYIH9HCFEzDwN6KNocKIUwA@ylxm3KPHUISXxo4dg0TGTF95jsqLEPWHI4pOVnLxsLFYceUVyGpORyYQhSXIcJNl6YeQS/m/mw38A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 55 bytes

```
Min@BlockMap[#~TrimmedMean~.2&,#,5,1]~NumberForm~{4,2}&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY4/b8IwFMT3fgpLICb3yf9jFoQ6dAtUKluUwYAlLHASpc5QIfLVQ/wyne7ud36OLt18dClc3PTr07FLoW3@qvVxSN2QKPlu@7k9/XeefO7Ikuas/vjpQ5OqqQzN/uvRXu6l66rVeOpDjP5aeteMIDZ0RTXl9XgY4tn3eTg@FRWvzbQnT6nAFpRICUKhSI5iJCWiADaHYgt8kSIjHIzGTonZMeCZtMtOgGYoJjsD0mJnGL5pNTrcGWALqTKpQWq8oAq8wASS@DMNzL7q6Q0)

Technical note: the TIO link includes `SetOptions[$Output, FormatType -> OutputForm]` in the header. I am not including this in the score, because it's not necessary in an actual Mathematica notebook: those are in `OutputForm` by default.

### Explanation

`BlockMap[f,#,5,1]` applies `f` to every block of 5 consecutive numbers. Here, `f` is `#~TrimmedMean~.2&`, which takes the mean after dropping the lowest and highest 20%.

We take the minimum of the results, and then `~NumberForm~{4,2}` puts the answer in the required format: at most 4 digits of precision, with 2 digits after the decimal.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 16 bytes

```
5l⟑sḢṪṁ;g:∆τ⌊3+Ḟ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCI1bOKfkXPhuKLhuarhuYE7ZzriiIbPhOKMijMr4bieIiwiIiwiWzE3LjE2LDE1LjA0LDE0LjY3LDE2LjU1LDE0Ljk5LDE3LjE2XSJd)

### How?

```
5l        # apertures, width 5
  ⟑       # map over each:
   s      # - sort
    Ḣ     # - drop head
     Ṫ    # - drop tail
      ṁ   # - average
       ;  # end map
        g # minimum

:       # dup
 ∆τ     # log10
   ⌊    # floor
    3+  # plus 3
      Ḟ # format to that many decimals
```

Comment: `∆τ⌊` = Length, so `:∆τ⌊` = `₅`

Comment: not for numbers?

Comment: Oh. `:L` should work

Comment: no, bc `:L` measures the length of the rational converted to a string, which is a fraction

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>131</s> <s>128</s> <s>125</s> <s>124</s> <s>154</s>  <s>138</s> 120 bytes

```javascript
x=>Math.min(...x[f='slice'](0,-4).map((_,i)=>x[f](i,i+5).sort((a,b)=>a-b)[f](1,4)).map(([a,b,c])=>(a+b+c)/3)).toFixed(2)
```

Too long. Will golf.

## Explanation

```javascript
x=>                              // declare function
    Math.min(...                // smallest of
       x[f='slice'](0,-4)        // slice of last 4 to avoid NaN / undefined, defining f as 'slice' to save bytes
       .map((_,i)=>              // for each, by index (current value doesn't matter for now)
         x[f](i,i+5)             // remember f is slice, so replace each with its chunk of 5 (x is untrimmed, slice doesn't modify original
         .sort((a,b)=>a-b)       // sort numerically
         [f](1,4)                // remove first and last
       ).map(([a,b,c])=>         // for each, taking all 3 elements
         (a+b+c)/3               // take average
       )              
     )                           // end of min, so now have smallest
   ).toFixed(2)                  // round + add 0s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY7LboMwEEV/JbvYwkz9xizIsrt@AUKVIdC6IjgKqOLvqT10dTQ@93rmx//6dXiF51Yu8T4eU3Psze3Db9/wCAsBgL2dmus6h2G8doSzUlN4@CchnyzQ5pZsRwILhaGwxtdGiGd9evdlT7MSTNP/QpsMG7okiS/6YqBvKqktvod9vBNJjyEua5xHmOMXmUgra1AVu6gKhGEXacDWCRoUT6jB6eQ0uBxRIDVCCYRVKVIB15gUJ2yOCLAGnZZp4iBy0p09CYYjbJ4sKIfOcvzTnUfUHB@xboGfBZ0LBpTBRbrCRVxiEg80wF1H6fEH)

Comment: This [fails](https://tio.run/##NY5NboNADIX3PUWW4zI4nl@GBblBTxBlMVCSUtEQBVQRKXeng0lXz/b3nu3v@BvH5t7dpvw6fLbLuVrm6iDER5y@8CfOAhFnHPuuaQXJ3EIa3oR4yA6qwz/oZJc5wHG4T0JEWScU8xpeVEkLr9gxQdmcEhcxq7MG9gbgXRFl6OBJsE/l29IM13HoW@yHiziLoy7RFHJnClRO7rRDXyaxaChJicEmZjGsFoPashjF4k2yFEiWnWoTv1oUesfM6tQRqtUZtpxGRyx@7TyawMwT7wzbEyXxkOMeaQvYNeDQOD5kCz5Emp38oEMKJ4DlDw) for the third test case

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Working on it

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Oops I was using Math.max instead of Math.min. It works now.

Comment: Unfortunately, from the question: "with exactly two decimal places (including trailing zeros)". For the third test case, yours outputs `28.3`

Comment: Damn it. Hold on while I patch in a regex.

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 106 bytes

```hs
printf"%.2f".g
g(h:t)|length t<4=99|y<-h:take 4t=min((sum y-maximum y-minimum y)/3)$g t
import Text.Printf
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY9La8MwEITv@hVLSMGGeCvrZTvYOfXYQ6E99uImsiPiF7ZCE8hvrys5kEMuw8fsaHZ1LKeTbprZtEM/WvjSF4sfo@lsRariex4WXL0gq1ZYkzo4bm14a3RX2yPYXBRZdrvmkXPLkwZhi9Z0QTCdW7hGbXkx7Z1Md6fwlYfrGiyJoud1c1uarjj0BEzung7BqMvDdvtp3bSOdm/9@afRIf7242HK17ta23fTaQJ9Hj14uTaowBRFvzEbB5s@JOCb5wRjBRKpAIEqAYVSOsoyIlFyEsdIKcT0WbMHkruyDHkC3LVJYBJVBkwgp@D8VAAXmLopRya88tir4sASv9hl4kWVm8aopPcFA04xdpl0yTOU1KtyrJCn3lfU96TLxox6x79S/jaXFC4pkUvfLBLfTJnP@Evch1Pim@nfvmrKepqj/TD8Aw)

The relevant function is `f`, which takes as input the array of times as a list of `Double`s. `f` returns a string representation of the best rolling AoE.

Having to import `Text.Printf` for this seems... *wrong*..., but I couldn't find any shorter way.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 29 bytes

```
﹪%.2f∕⌊ＥＥ⁻Ｌθ⁴✂θι⁺⁵ι¹⁻Σι⁺⌊ι⌈ι³
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY7NasMwEIRfRQQKCmwXSSvJMr3mWEMgx5CDcdxE4NjNj0Pf3t1VWoGG5ZvZkbpze@umdliW7S2PD91Mx3mY9OoN3dcK1CY/87HXTR7zZb7opv1@3TzOd/3Zj6fHWV/XoDzf3ZC7Xl9BZVDbgf3AI3O7Znlt7LhDULH/SwU07c/fLAcUsX4sy37vaqQKqEIbwAWMNTiPZIB58kAeE7uEzouSFY0ErkLjJWOLRnYtxiDcOyCDljOp5B0GIxp5jkhJeDTSk8qLtREiWxFNSXpOBqQgzb6SZuMkIz8JaNLhsLw/h18) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
           θ                    Input array
          Ｌ                     Length
         ⁻                      Subtract
            ⁴                   Literal 4
        Ｅ                       Map over implicit range
              θ                 Input array
             ✂                  Sliced
               ι                From current index
                ⁺⁵ι¹            Take five consecutive values
       Ｅ                        Map over slices
                      ι         Current slice
                     Σ          Sum
                    ⁻           Subtract
                         ι      Current slice
                        ⌊       Minimum
                       ⁺        Plus
                           ι    Current slice
                          ⌈     Maximum
      ⌊                         Take the minimum
     ∕                          Divide by
                            ³   Literal `3`
﹪%.2f                           Round to two decimal places
                                Implicitly print
```

Comment: Just comes and casually outgolfs everyone by 3x as much. I would upvote this if I had any left.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) v2.0a0, 17 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

+4 bytes for the dumb output format :/

```
ã5 ®ÍÅÔÅx÷3Ãrm x2
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=2.0a0&code=4zUgrs3F1MV49zPDcm0geDI&input=WzI5LjM3IDM3LjE1IDI1LjY5IDI0LjMwIDI5Ljg0IDM0Ljg3IDMzLjI0IDMzLjMxIDMzLjYzIDI3LjA0IDI5LjE0IDI5LjY0IDMxLjY1IDI3LjQyIDMwLjEzIDI4LjMxIDMyLjUwIDMyLjYxIDM2LjM4IDI4LjYwIDMzLjg1IDI1LjkwIDI4LjQyIDM2LjAwIDMyLjQxIDM1LjM1IDI5LjQ3IDMxLjAyIDI4Ljg3IDM1LjA4XQ)

```
ã5 ®ÍÅÔÅx÷3Ãrm x2     :Implicit input of array
ã5                    :Sub-arrays of length 5
   ®                  :Map
    Í                 :  Sort
     Å                :  Slice off first element (the minimum)
      Ô               :  Reverse
       Å              :  Slice off first element (the maximum)
        x             :  Reduce by addition
         ÷3           :  Divide by 3
           Ã          :End map
            r         :Reduce by
             m        :  Minimum
               x2     :Force to 2 decimal places
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>58</s> 56 bytes

```ruby
->a{"%.2f"%a.each_cons(5).map{|b|b.sort[1,3].sum/3}.min}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZDBasMwEETv/QoRCLTgTiWttJYO7Y8YU@xQ0xychDg@lCTf7q7WlPbQ03i1b3YGn@f@axlel@e37rrZwg@bbYePbvf5vjsepsf4hLE7XW/9rcd0PF8aV1GLaR5f6I5xf7gvp/kymaFpajiuTIQNlQngujKMGMt3zm378IM5B2sr4@w/kn@HPw6fQXKNJEDO@QjOIgEkrOyS5FFAKgjBBxVyKkyC1FpJSLcKF8SBo@6Cl8nCFTKtPo9oVbhMDEq6Y6s301oiW31UO2tvMYRiiKCoQaHWIOuV1ILye1LbLt8)

#### Explanation

It's quite straightforward actually:

- get all sets of 5 consecutive elements using `each_cons(5)`
- sort them, then get the 3 elements in the middle to discard min and max
- calculate average
- get minimum average value and format with 2 decimal places

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 153 bytes

```
func[b][head insert at tail to""round/to 100 * first sort
collect[loop(length? b)- 4[keep average copy/part next
sort copy/part b 5 3 b: next b]]1 -2"."]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVC7TsQwEOzzFaNUgITP7yTX8A@0kYs8nLuIKI58PgRfH7wBIYSL0WpmdnbX0Y/7qx9bV0xn7NN9HdretVffjZjXm48JXULq5gUplGUM93U8pQDBOZ4wzfGWcAsxFUNYFj@kdglhe1j8eknXF/SPz9Dtm/cbuncfu4vHELbP09bl3NV/pIJ6/3A9DBT68yGid07gWZasdPsUou@GK@J9RVsgv7ZiwsIwrqGZrWCZMblqGvctC8HykoL/x@a3/DHKhqkKKscZSMNsA6mZ4sh8raE0q7OqmNSEShBaBVnR5OwRB9qsCmYN8VpCcSaypz78khlOaHNtmaqJt5xy6mNiw4mhLku7ZafOTsOUoWRdUTKX5KFN8sW1K1y7xXlNmOhH3P4F)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-MList::Util=sum,min,max -a`, <s>81</s> 67 bytes

```perl
printf"%.2f",(min map{sum(@b=@F[$_..$_+4])-min(@b)-max@b}0..@F-5)/3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZBPa8MwDMXv/RQidNCyRJP/yU5HIaeetuNO2ygprBBo0tBkMBj76vOk3Hf52Tw9P8kaP26XkPN464b5XNyhPRflpu8G6Nvxe/rsN81p3xxe10fE9fHev28rKYooZ/vVnH4IsTlUYfvg8uMSUrwNRY5oGAKSB48cgTEEudX1yhASwX@MChasbI0ugpOcADYg12A9OgLRkwfnMUnVofVKZ5TswEZtKR6zkKVqkIPq3oIjNOJJi99iICXLndEl1Zk0Jy0da1JFX@k86vTiDOiCJvuoyWTVo5PIV9PvdZy76zDl6vmpm@bd7mXuLntZYSkbK2VbuWr/AA)